# Typescript "Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types" when using enums

Tags: typescript

I am getting the error "Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types" in the comparison with enums, but not with integer values:

```
enum E {
    A,
    B, 
    C,
    D,
    E,
    F
}

let x: E


// Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'E.A' and 'E.B'
if (x !== E.A || x !== E.B) {

}


// OK
if (x !== 0 || x !== 1) {

}
```

Aren't these two examples equivalent? What is the cause of the error?

---

### Update

Actually it helps to consider the equivalent `&&` expression:

```
if (!(x === E.A && x === E.B)) {

}

if (!(x === 0 || x === 1)) {

}
```

In the first example, compiler can infer that `E.A` and `E.B` are members of union types and cannot be equal, so gives the error, but it doesn't know (care) about integers.

Comment: What language version are you using? The error I get in the playground isn't "Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types", it's "Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'E.A' and 'E.B'". When the compiler statically knows that `x` is `E.A`, it'll disallow comparisons with any other type that isn't `E.A`.

Comment: Actually, the updated condition `!(x === E.A && x === E.B)` still makes no sense. `x` cannot be identical to `E.A` and `E.B` at the same time.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was not clear enough, but I can reason about the updated condition better than the negated one that it doesn't make sense. But `!(x === 1 && x === 1)` also doesn't make sense, I wonder why TypeScript doesn't complain about it.

Comment: There may be an error in the "Update" section: `(x !== 0 || x !== 1)` should become `!(x === 0 && x === 1)`, and not `!(x === 0 || x === 1)` as appears above (commenting rather than editing as I'm not 100% certain I didn't miss something...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an identical example in the [TypeScript documentation about enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> ```
> enum E {
>     Foo,
>     Bar,
> }
>
> function f(x: E) {
>     if (x !== E.Foo || x !== E.Bar) {
>         //             ~~~~~~~~~~~
>         // Error! Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'E.Foo' and 'E.Bar'.
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In that example, we first checked whether x was not E.Foo. If that
>   check succeeds, then our || will short-circuit, and the body of the
>   ‘if’ will get run. However, if the check didn’t succeed, then x can
>   only be E.Foo, so it doesn’t make sense to see whether it’s equal to
>   E.Bar.

The condition in your example thus makes no sense to the compiler. It will always evaluate to true anyway.

> Because of that, TypeScript can catch silly bugs where we might be comparing values incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. I updated the question with the insight that I got from reading the documentation.